# Azure Analysis Service Deployment through

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to deploy Azure Analysis Service by using Powershell. Can someone guide me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-create-powershell

Comment: You may also want to take a look at how to improve your questions on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask